# define geofence around location stored in array

Tags: arrays, swift, geofencing

I am working on an app where I have a set of pre-defined co-ordinates stored in an array like the one below:

```
var SpeedcameraLocationDictionary: [[String : AnyObject]] = [
    ["camindex": "1a", "Latitude":xxxx, "Longitude":xxxx,"Distance":34, "legalspeed":110],
    ["camindex": "1b", "Latitude":xxxx, "Longitude":xxxx,"Distance":34, "legalspeed":110],
    ["camindex": "2a", "Latitude":xxxx, "Longitude":xxxx,"Distance":26, "legalspeed":110],
    ["camindex": "2b", "Latitude":xxxx, "Longitude":xxxx,"Distance":26, "legalspeed":110]]
```

What I want to do is, when the users location matches any lat & long in the array (+ or - 5 meters) , start doing some calculations. I have variables set up to hold the lat & long of the user, and the relevant CLLocation manager. Implanting on checking the users location every 30 secs, so i have a timer set up to trigger at 30sec intervals.

I believe I need to set up a geofence around the relevant point, but I'm not really sure how to do the check & set up.

I imagine it would be along the lines of the following:

```
 if Timer = 30secs
let region = CLCircularRegion(center: Latitudefromarray,longitudefromarray, radius: 5,)
        if (Latitude +/- 5m == region AND longitude +/- 5m == region)

    do calculations....
```

could somebody either point me in the direction of a tutorial that could help me achieve this goal, or provide some sample code to achieve the goal I'm after? i have been following [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift) but am struggling to adapt it to my needs.

Thanks